# refresh the action of a IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, refresh

I have a `UIButton` that scrolls my `UICollectionView` to the right. The button is added to the superview of my `UICollectionView` soo it floats on top of the cells.
But I can only let the `UIAction` take place once. How do I replicate the action or refresh the button so that I can use it again.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(910, 345 , 100, 100);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.collectionView.superview addSubview:button];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeContentOffset:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)changeContentOffset:(id)sender {
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(910, -65) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Button action will be called every time u clicked on it..Anyway add the button action before adding button as subview to collectionView..Anywhere  u are removing the button from collectionview?

Comment: Put all the button code at cellForItemAtIndexPath instead of ViewDidLoad and also add button to contentView not the collectionView.superview..

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button to self.view

or

In your `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

method you can simply add the button to cell content view `[cell.contentView addSubview: button];`

Comment: it will still only scroll once. My button is working, but it only scrolls once

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint in the line inside the IBAction, did you stop only once ? According to your question, you want to scroll right each time you click on that button, but your method doesn't do so.

The method set the `contentOffset` of your `UICollectionView`the first time you tap on the button, but for the other times, since the `UICollectionView`is already shifted, you cannot see any change. Try replacing your method with :

```
- (IBAction)changeContentOffset:(id)sender { 
    CGPoint offset = self.collectionView;
    offset.x += 910;
    offset.y -= 65;
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this method to depend of the collectionView actual position...

```
 self.collectionView.paginateEnabled = YES;


- (IBAction)changeContentOffset:(id)sender {
   float x = cellWidth + self.collectionView.contentOffset.x;
   [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(910, x) animated:YES];

}
```